# Can I hide my location whilst using mine and my company's VPN?

Tags: vpn

My laptop must be connected to my company's VPN (Global Protect) before I can be able to work at home. I try to connect my Express VPN at the same time to stop my company's VPN  from "seeing" my physical location when I'm in another country. Please how do I do this?
I try to connect my Express VPN same time when the Global Protect is ON, but it won't let me. The company's VPN won't connect except I disconnect from my Express VPN.
Please assist me here as I don't mean any harm but just want to be with my family abroad at the same time. And I don't want to lose my job. But I am willing to do my work well but still be with my family.

What do I do to stop my employer from seeing my location when i am abroad?

Comment: *"What do I do to stop my employer from seeing my location when i am abroad?"* - basically you want to bypass security policies by your employer for your own gain. This is not a website which helps with such activity. If possible get instead the permission from your employer to connect from a specific remote location instead of trying to hide your real location.

Comment: Thanks for that. I really do appreciate

Comment: Just saying: This would get me fired. Company insists that I only have company equipment in places with legal standards similar to the UK. So no travelling abroad unless I have company’s permission.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your operating system and TCP/IP stack, it's not so clear-cut that you *can*. Running two VPNs requires establishing which is the "inner" and which is the "outer" VPN, and this means the two software drivers might need to collaborate to some extent.

At the most basic level, some VPN softwares (and your company's might well be one of those) require that the carrier interface is *physical* (i.e. not a VPN itself).

However, as I see it, if your company allows you to work through VPN this means that they should **not** be concerned about where you're connecting from. That is the *point* of a VPN. So, have you tried *asking*? They might be all right with allowing you to work from wherever you wish, provided the work gets done. Actually, this once happened to me, they might be ecstatic and assign you to some specific task that would benefit from the different time zone (or exempt you from Skype calls at certain awkward times).

And on the other hand, if your company only allows specific places to act as VPN endpoints, this means they require the additional security - they might not want you to get your laptop screen in any old Internet café where someone might be able to snoop from behind your shoulder. If this is the case, it stands to reason that they will have instrumentation in place to help detect non-compliances: the simplest one is check out from which IP you're connecting.

In which case, if you fire up your private VPN from anywhere in the world, *including your own home*, and thus appear to be located in PrivateVPN's rack space, the fact you're nesting two VPNs will be immediately obvious and trigger some alarm.

Also, in the case of the time zone, you might find yourself forced to stay awake at night, or be unexplainably unavailable during normal workhours when your colleagues might wish to communicate with you.

Comment: Thanks!!! These statements are worth considering - "However, as I see it, if your company allows you to work through VPN this means that they should not be concerned about where you're connecting from. That is the point of a VPN. So, have you tried asking? They might be all right with allowing you to work from wherever you wish, provided the work gets done. Actually, this once happened to me, they might be ecstatic and assign you to some specific task that would benefit from the different time zone (or exempt you from Skype calls at certain awkward times)"

Comment: Wrong. Just because the VPN is safe doesn’t mean a country’s police can’t enter my hotel room and take my hardware, together with rubber hose cryptography methods.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, that is true. On the other hand, were *that* in the cards, then I imagine the company would **never** have hired anyone with hostageable relatives in vulnerable countries, and/or would have warned against vacationing in those countries, with or without computing equipment.